# Akka Management serving HTTP over HTTPS

Tags: scala, ssl, akka, tls1.2, akka-cluster

I am trying to secure the Akka Management port of a Scala microservice with TLS by starting Akka Management programatically on port 8558 via `AkkaManagement:withHttpsConnectionContext()`.

When the Scala service is run, it reads from the configuration and starts Akka Management fine, but does not appear to be operating with TLS encryption enabled.

```
~$ telnet localhost 8558
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /cluster/members HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: akka-http/10.4.0
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2023 20:26:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 439
```

From what I can tell, Akka Management is serving HTTP from what should be the HTTPS port, and not encrypting the response.

```
:~$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:8558 -state -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
write to 0x56097b12c740 [0x56097b13ee80] (283 bytes => 283 (0x11B))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 16 01 00 01-12 03 03 05 27 1c 50 1b   ............'.P.
0010 - e6 b6 23 5a e5 da d5 48-29 33 51 08 13 fb b6 aa   ..#Z...H)3Q.....
0020 - 23 f4 2e 44 93 75 95 97-59 9a 1c 20 99 b0 36 06   #..D.u..Y.. ..6.
0030 - 1f 3d 79 d0 d8 e8 36 7e-41 5e 2e ff 70 f7 ce a5   .=y...6~A^..p...
0040 - 0a 5a 56 e4 a9 fc 15 09-d0 3c a7 9b 00 3e 13 02   .ZV......<...>..
0050 - 13 03 13 01 c0 2c c0 30-00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa   .....,.0........
0060 - c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e c0 24-c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27   .+./...$.(.k.#.'
0070 - 00 67 c0 0a c0 14 00 39-c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d   .g.....9.....3..
0080 - 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c 00 35-00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 8b   ...=.<.5./......
0090 - 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02-00 0a 00 0c 00 0a 00 1d   ................
00a0 - 00 17 00 1e 00 19 00 18-00 23 00 00 00 16 00 00   .........#......
00b0 - 00 17 00 00 00 0d 00 2a-00 28 04 03 05 03 06 03   .......*.(......
00c0 - 08 07 08 08 08 09 08 0a-08 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06   ................
00d0 - 04 01 05 01 06 01 03 03-03 01 03 02 04 02 05 02   ................
00e0 - 06 02 00 2b 00 05 04 03-04 03 03 00 2d 00 02 01   ...+........-...
00f0 - 01 00 33 00 26 00 24 00-1d 00 20 4e 63 c8 62 95   ..3.&.$... Nc.b.
0100 - f3 8e a4 b2 04 44 1a 83-6e 53 99 4b ef d0 f7 51   .....D..nS.K...Q
0110 - eb 95 b5 8c 1d 3c f7 f7-fa c1 1b                  .....<.....
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
read from 0x56097b12c740 [0x56097b135c63] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 48 54 54 50 2f                                    HTTP/
SSL_connect:error in error
139911147234624:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:331:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 283 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read from 0x56097b12c740 [0x56097b123f00] (8192 bytes => 189 (0xBD))
0000 - 31 2e 31 20 34 30 30 20-42 61 64 20 52 65 71 75   1.1 400 Bad Requ
0010 - 65 73 74 0d 0a 53 65 72-76 65 72 3a 20 61 6b 6b   est..Server: akk
0020 - 61 2d 68 74 74 70 2f 31-30 2e 34 2e 30 0d 0a 44   a-http/10.4.0..D
0030 - 61 74 65 3a 20 46 72 69-2c 20 32 37 20 4a 61 6e   ate: Fri, 27 Jan
0040 - 20 32 30 32 33 20 32 30-3a 33 36 3a 30 32 20 47    2023 20:36:02 G
0050 - 4d 54 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e-65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20   MT..Connection:
0060 - 63 6c 6f 73 65 0d 0a 43-6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54   close..Content-T
0070 - 79 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78-74 2f 70 6c 61 69 6e 3b   ype: text/plain;
0080 - 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74-3d 55 54 46 2d 38 0d 0a    charset=UTF-8..
0090 - 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d-4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20   Content-Length:
00a0 - 32 33 0d 0a 0d 0a 55 6e-73 75 70 70 6f 72 74 65   23....Unsupporte
00b0 - 64 20 48 54 54 50 20 6d-65 74 68 6f 64            d HTTP method
read from 0x56097b12c740 [0x56097b123f00] (8192 bytes => 0 (0x0))
```

It also looks like attempting to access Akka Management with TLS is also failing completely.

I'm seeing the following log message on the microservice when using the openssl command:
`[WARN] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl] [] [inbound-transaction-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65] [] [] [] [] - Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Unsupported HTTP method: The HTTP method started with 0x16 rather than any known HTTP method from 192.168.96.1:39184. Perhaps this was an HTTPS request sent to an HTTP endpoint?`

I tried starting Akka Management programatically with TLS encryption, and got unencrypted HTTP instead.

Here is the code used to setup HTTPS and start Akka Management:

```
def getHttpsConnectionContext(config: HttpsConfig): SSLContext = {
  val keystore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")

  val keystoreFile: InputStream =
    getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(config.keystoreFile)

  val keystorePassword = config.keystorePassword.toCharArray

  keystore.load(keystoreFile, keystorePassword)

  val keyManagerFactory: KeyManagerFactory =
    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
  keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, keystorePassword)

  val trustManagerFactory: TrustManagerFactory =
    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
  trustManagerFactory.init(keystore)

  val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")

  sslContext.init(
    keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers,
    trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers,
    new SecureRandom
  )

  sslContext
}
```

```
val httpsConfig: HttpsConfig =
  HttpsConfig(
    actorSystem.settings.config,
    "akka.moo.https"
  ) match {
    case Some(value) => value
    case None => throw new ConfigurationException("Bad HTTPS config")
  }
val sslContext: SSLContext =
  HttpsContext.getHttpsConnectionContext(httpsConfig)
val httpsServer: HttpsConnectionContext =
  ConnectionContext.httpsServer(sslContext)

val management = AkkaManagement(actorSystem)
management.start(_.withHttpsConnectionContext(httpsServer))
```

I'm not sure what the problem here is.
Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: I think you are going to have to post your HTTPS setup code. See the tests for what it should look like: https://github.com/akka/akka-management/blob/178497c1e454009b5727588c666f5619a84a1c18/management/src/test/scala/akka/management/AkkaManagementHttpEndpointSpec.scala#L162

Comment: @DavidOgren It seems like I'm doing exactly what the tests do.